# Month and Day functions treating dates as 1 day back

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, date-time

Can any one explain this. I have 3 columns, a date column, month and day columns. The month and day columns are calculated columns of the date column.
DOB - Date/Time (Date only format)
DOB_Month - calculated column - MONTH(DOB)
DOB_Day - calculated column - DAY(DOB)

I entered a couple of records. Some of them work just fine. Some - the Month and Day calculations appear to be treating the DOB date as one day back.  NOTE: all of these records were entered at the same time. If I edit a value in the list (ie: name), it saves out the record with the appropriate Month/Day values. Within 5 minutes, the list refreshes with the wrong values. Again --- ONLY A FEW RECORDS ... not all of them.

Splain??

[image]

Comment: What is the regional, language settings and date format selected for this site? Maybe it is causing this problem.

Comment: Indeed like Ganesh I had similar problem, but behaviour was consistent and all dates were off by day. Please share the formulas you use for calculation.

Comment: Ganesh's direction was correct. I discovered the regional setting was not set properly. After correcting, all is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the site's regional setting was set to Pacific time, where I am located in Easter time. Once I adjusted the setting, all the formulas worked properly. Days later - the data is still "in good standing".

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, your problem cannot be reproduced, which may be related to the formula you use.
I used the following formula to test and it worked fine.
[image: DOB_Month column]
[image: DOB_Day column]
[image: The Result]
You can try to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: As Ganesh suggests - it was related to my site's regional settings. Once I configured the correct setting, all my entries started working properly. The inconsistent treatment was odd - and a day later, the 11 entries that were wrongly set went back to being wrong again. I deleted those entries and re-entered them - and now all is working fine.